# how to center rotatetext parbox?

Tags: rotating, parbox

the code below puts the text MNIST not at center. I want to center it align it with the text SSIM. I change parbox to different values of cm but nothing change. How ?

```
\begin{figure}[t]
    \scriptsize
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{ccc}
            \rotatebox{90}{\parbox{1cm}{\Large{MNIST}}} & \includegraphics[width=0.38\textwidth]{ablation/mnistssim_final.png}& \includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{ablation/mnistmse.png}\\
            %\multicolumn{2}{c}{MNIST}\\
%       \end{tabular}
%       \caption{MSE and SSIM on the moving MNIST action dataset with various \textbf{M} window size and $\mathcla{H}$ output horizon configurations. Timestep is the prediction extent $\mathbf{T}$.}
        %\label{fig:ablationmnist-inputoutput}
%   \end{center}
%\end{figure}

%\begin{figure}[t]
%   \begin{center}
%       \begin{tabular}{cc}
            KTH & \includegraphics[width=0.38\textwidth]{ablation/kthssim.png}& \includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{ablation/kthpsnr.png}\\
            \multicolumn{2}{c}{KTH}\\
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{The effect of \textbf{M} window size and the output horizon $\mathcal{H}$ on the performance. First row shows SSIM and MSE on the moving MNIST action dataset, and the second row shows SSIM and PSNR on the KTH action dataset.}
        \label{fig:ablationkth-inputoutput}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you make your MWE compilable? You can use example images from ``graphicx`` instead of your own images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `adjustbox` and the `origin=` key for `\rotatebox`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[export, demo]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
    \scriptsize
    \centering
        \begin{tabular}{ccc}
            \rotatebox[origin =c]{90}{\Large MNIST\enspace} & \includegraphics[width=0.38\textwidth, valign=c]{ablation/mnistssim_final.png}& \includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth, valign=c]{ablation/mnistmse.png}\\\\
\addlinespace
            KTH & \includegraphics[width=0.38\textwidth, valign=c]{ablation/kthssim.png}& \includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth, valign=c]{ablation/kthpsnr.png}\\
\addlinespace
            \multicolumn{2}{c}{KTH}\\
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{The effect of \textbf{M} window size and the output horizon $\mathcal{H}$ on the performance. First row shows SSIM and MSE on the moving MNIST action dataset, and the second row shows SSIM and PSNR on the KTH action dataset.}
        \label{fig:ablationkth-inputoutput}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why adjustbox instead of graphicx?

Comment: To use the  `valign` key (note the `export` option at load time).